# Plotting data from cell

Tags: matlab

I have multiple geopoint data inside of a (1x2) data cell. How can I plot all of this data onto one map within MATLAB?

I have tried to append before but obviously it isn't what I want. I'm really trying to understand the best method.

```
clear;
clc;
% Specify folder where the files live 
myFolder = 'C:\Users\J87662\Desktop\GPX Data Files';
% Check to make sure folder exists. Warns user if doesn't. 
if ~isdir(myFolder)
    errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
    uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
    return;
end
% Get a list of all files in the folder with the desired file name pattern.
theFiles = dir(fullfile(myFolder, '*.gpx')); % Using .gpx as the desired file type.
% Number of files in the folder 
n = numel(theFiles);
data = cell(1,n);
for k=1:n
    % Read each file 
    data{k} = gpxread(fullfile( myFolder, theFiles(k).name )); 
    baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
end
```

When trying to use data(1,1).Latitude, I get the error "Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object."

Comment: If you need sample GPX files, use this site: http://www.wandermap.net/en/route/3535534-sample-gpx/

Comment: I see you don't approve any answers, please consider approving answers that solves your questions.

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that. I'm still learning my way around this community. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing into cell arrays requires the use of {} rather than (). Try data{1, 1}.Latitude instead (since you have only a single column, data{1}.Latitude should also work).

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to do! Thank you so much!